# How to embed string condition in linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I want to apply few conditions in my linq query. My scenario is I am fetching records from a table and if user select some criteria then apply condition according to. So what i want to do is

```
var linq = from p in Post select p
//now if user apply that condition
string id = "1"; //Here 1 is what user inputs
string condition = where p.id == id 
//then it executes query like this 
linq = from p in Post condition select p
```

Can i do this in linq if yes then how

Comment: are you guaranteed to always have a condition? or you want the condition only if the user specifies it?

Comment: Yes i want to apply if user specify condition otherwise show all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var linq = from p in Post select p;

//now if user apply that condition
string id = "1"; //Here 1 is what user inputs

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
{
    linq = linq.Where(p => p.id == id);
}

return linq.ToList(); // or whatever you want to do with it at this point
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to look into dynamic linq or depending on how complex you want to make the condition use expression trees

You might want to try:

```
string id = "1";
string condition = "p.id == " + id;
var linq = from p in Post 
           where (condition) 
           select p;
```

or with a lambda:

```
string id = "1";
string condition = "p => p.id == " + id;
var linq = Post.Where(condition).SingleOrDefault();
```

See the following:

[Scott Gu's post on Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

[Querying Entity with LINQ using Dyanmic Field Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463479/querying-entity-with-linq-using-dyanmic-field-name)

[Basics of Linq Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)

Comment: I think expression trees are overkill for this

Comment: Agreed, but if Franz ends up doing something like a search function where the user selects the field to search as well as the condition, then an expression tree would be the answer

Comment: var linq = Post.Where(condition).SingleOrDefault(); This line doesnot compile it gives error