# Accessing a given field of a given table from dbContext in SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-entities, entity

I want to select a row from a Database using LINQ to Entities in Entity Framework in C#.

My arguements to method are :

- string Database Context
- string TableName
- string fieldName/column

I want to select the row from table "TableName" dynamically based on these three parameters where "fieldName" matches a certain value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need entity framework to do something like this, you can use helper methods provided into dbContext to execute your custom query:

```
  public List<T> ListElements(string tableName, string columnName) {
    var db = new DbContext();
    var query = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}", tableName, columnName);
    var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query);
    return data;
  }
```

You can use this method to list items into table with specific type.
Suppose you want to display all ids of a table named "Users" you can write this code:

```
var userIds = ListElements<int>("Users", "Id");
```

Comment: Thats the way I am doing it now. I just wanted to remove the hard coded string and do it dynamically

Comment: OK, now is different, I suggest you to see this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463479/querying-entity-with-linq-using-dyanmic-field-name, hope it can help